# jQuery - showing first three images of a gallery; hiding the remainder

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an list of images with the following markup:

```
 <a href="#" id="toggle-16561" onclick="toggleImages(16561); return false;">show images</a>
 <div class='image-container-box clearfix' id='image-container-box-16561'>
      <span class='image-box'>
        <a href="/images/1.jpg"><img src="/images/1_thumb.jpg" /></a>
      </span>
      <span class='image-box'>
        <a href="/images/2.jpg"><img src="/images/2_thumb.jpg" /></a>
      </span>

      etc ....
    </div>
</div>
```

I could have a bunch of these on a web page (like 20 or more). I originally didn't want to show any of the thumbs and thus have all the .images-container-box set to hide. I'd like to have the first 3 images be shown and the remainder be hidden. It seems what I want to do is say on initial load hide all the .image-container-box.image-box that are > 3 in the img array of the element. How would I do this?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".image-container-box .image-box:gt(2)").hide();
```

or:

```
$(".image-container-box .image-box").slice(2).hide();
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/CfXcY/)

Answer (score 1):

It's jQuery's [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

`$(".images-container-box").slice(0,2).show();`

`$(".images-container-box").slice(3).hide();`

Using `slice` is more efficient than `gt(n)`, `lt(n)` or the other positional selectors because jQuery somewhy loops through the entire set when evaulating `gt, lt, etc..`.

Comment: `slice` is a JavaScript method.

Comment: Ah, okay. "The jQuery .slice() method is patterned after the JavaScript .slice() method for arrays." I was under the impression that it simply used the Array.slice prototype.

Answer (score 0):

First hide them using CSS (if you havent done that already):

```
.image-container-box{display:none}
```

Then show the first three using jQuery and the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```
$('.image-container-box:lt(3)').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS version:

```
.image-box {display:none;}
.image-box:first-child, .image-box:nth-child(2), .image-box:nth-child(3) {display: block;}
```