# jquery - 3 images to load on multiple instances of a class on a single page

Tags: jquery

I asked this question earlier today [jQuery - showing first three images of a gallery; hiding the remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352160/jquery-showing-first-three-images-of-a-gallery-hiding-the-remainder) but when testing out other pieces and reseeding, I realized that the sol'n only worked for the first `image-container-box`. Unfortunately, I'll be having multiple `image-container-box`'s per page. Is there a way to tell jquery each of the image-container-box rather than just the first? Or, did I misunderstand the accepted answer?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You will have make use of jQuery's each to apply the slicing code to each one.

```
$('.image-container-box').each( function() { 
    $(this).children('.image-box').slice(2).hide(); //or use find if image-box isn't a direct descendent of image-container-box
});
```